# How to access the row data from a single cell in Material React Table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-table, material-react-table

I'm using https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/row-actions

I can render the cell a specific way according to this example

```
const columns = useMemo(
        () => [
            {
                header: 'Relevance',
                accessorKey: 'rating', 
                size: 40, 
                Cell: ({cell}) => {
                    return <span>{cell.getValue()}</span>;
                },
                
            },
)
```

but how do I access the full row data from inside the span?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`accessorFn`](https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/data-columns#method-2---using-an-accessorfn-and-id) property to get the values of the row.

```js
const columns = useMemo(
  () => [
    {
      header: "Relevance",
      accessorFn: (row) => row,
      size: 40,
      Cell: ({ cell }) => {
        const row = cell.getValue();
        return <span>{row.theValueYouWant}</span>;
      },
    },
  ],
  []
);
```

See here [a live preview](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-hofstadter-0mt84q?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: In typescript, if I want to create a common component for `Cell`, I need to access the type of `Cell`. Anyone know, how we can do that?